# Something wrong with multi dimensionals matrixes and the functions

Tags: c, matrix

firstly Ι wrote a programma that invert a matrix...but now i wanted to seperate the first programm in function and now it has a bug that i cant spot

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#define  Row        2
#define  Column     3

int  printb(int board[2][3]);
int revrsboard(int board1[2][3],int board2[3][2]);

int main(){
int board1[Row][Column]={ {1,2,3},   // ο αρχικος πινακας
               {4,5,6}
               };

int board2[Column][Row]={0};
int  printb(board1); //ektyposh pinaka
printf("\n");
int  revrsboard(board1,board2);  //anastyrofh kai ektyposh


return 0;
}


//print 1
int  initb(int board[2][3]){
int k,l ;

  for (k=0;k<2;k++){
    for(l=0;l<3;l++){
        printf("%4d |",board[k][l]);
    }
printf("\n");
          }

}

// reversing print
int  revrsboard(int board1[Row][Column],int board2[Column][Row]) {
int i=0 ,j=0,k,l ;
for(i=0;i<Row;i++){
    for(j=0;j<Column;j++){
        board2[j][i]=board1[i][j];
    }
}

for (k=0;k<3;k++){
    for(l=0;l<2;l++){
        printf("%4d |",board2[k][l]);
    }
printf("\n");
}

}
```

firstly  i used only the main func and the programm was running perfectly .

but i wanted to rewrite my programm  using more functions this time   and now... when i do compile and run it prints nothing

so i want some help to figure out how i can use functions and multidimensionals matrixes right

Comment: Please indent your code properly if you expect others to read it.

Comment: `int  printb(board1); //ektyposh pinaka` isn't how you call a function, `printb(board1);` is. Unfortunately the `printb` function doesn't exist in the code you've shown. The `initb` and `revrsboard` functions both say they will return an `int` but neither of them does. You probably want the return type to be `void` instead.

Comment: If we assume `initb` was really supposed to be `printb`, fix the return types, and actually call the functions we get this: https://godbolt.org/z/enfM1bx6q  Adopting a consistent formatting style is important. Code that is hard to read is also hard to write, modify, and debug.

Comment: ⟼Remember, it's always important, *especially* when learning and asking questions on Stack Overflow, to keep your code as organized as possible. [Consistent indentation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indentation_style) helps communicate structure and, importantly, intent, which helps us navigate quickly to the root of the problem without spending a lot of time trying to decode what's going on. What you have here is not only inconsistent, it implies structure that simply isn't there.

Answer (score 4):

This line in function `main`

```
int  revrsboard(board1,board2);  //anastyrofh kai ektyposh
```

does NOT call a function. It simply declares that this function exists, and will return an `int` if it is ever called.

To call the function, just call:

```
revrsboard(board1,board2);   //anastyrofh kai ektyposh
```

(without the `int` in front of it)

---

Also, you have declared that function `revrsboard` will return an `int`-value when it is done. But the body of the function does not have ***any*** return statements in it.

I suggest you should change it to be `void revrsboard(int board1[Row][Column],int board2[Column][Row]);`, which indicates the function does not have a return value.

Comment: Re “It simply declares that this function… will return an int if it is ever called”: Actually, it declares that if the function returns a value, it will be an `int`. The C standard neither requires a function to return (it can `longjmp` or exit the program or loop forever) nor requires functions that return to return a value, even if they are declared with a non-`void` return type.

Answer (score 2):

You aren't actually *calling* your `printb` and `revrsboard` functions from `main`; you're just *declaring* them.

```
int  printb(board1);
```

*declares* `printb` as a function that returns `int`; it doesn't actually *call* `printb`.

Your `main` function should look more like this (slightly reformatted for easier readability, at least by my standards):

```
int main()
{
  int board1[Row][Column]= { 
    {1,2,3},   
    {4,5,6}
  };

  int board2[Column][Row]={0};

  printb(board1); // *call* printb
  printf("\n");
  revrsboard(board1,board2);  // *call* revrsboard

  return 0;
}
```

*Why* are `printb` and `revrsboard` declared to return `int` when they don't actually return anything?  You should declare/define them as returning `void` instead:

```
void  printb(int board[2][3]);
void  revrsboard(int board1[2][3],int board2[3][2]);
```

---

Some additional information:

You need to be aware that array expressions "decay" to pointer expressions under most circumstances, and that what your functions are receiving are pointers, not arrays.

Except when it is the operand of the `sizeof`, `_Alignof`, or unary `&` operators<sup>1</sup>, an *expression* of type "N-element array of `T`" will be converted, or "decay", to an expression of type "pointer to `T`" and the value of the expression will be the address of the first element of the array.  If you have an array

```
int foo[10];
```

and you pass it as an argument to a function

```
bar( foo );
```

that's equivalent to writing

```
bar( &foo[0] );
```

If you define `bar` as

```
void bar( int a[10] ) { ... }
```

that parameter declaration will be "adjusted" to

```
void bar( int *a ) { ... }
```

and what `bar` is actually dealing with is a pointer, not an array.  Since the array subscript operation `a[i]` is *defined* as `*(a + i)`, you can use the subscript operator `[]` on both array and pointer expressions.

Because of this behavior it's a good idea to pass the array size as a separate parameter:

```
bar( foo, 10 );
...
void bar( int *a, size_t size )
{
  ...
  for ( size_t i = 0; i < size; i++ )
    do_something_with( a[i] );
  ...
}
```

It works the same for 2D arrays; an expression of type "N-element array of M-element array of `T`" will "decay" to an expression of type "pointer to M-element array of `T`", so when you call

```
printb( board1 );
```

that's equivalent to

```
printb( &board1[0] );
```

and what `printb` actually receives is a pointer to a *3-element array* of `int`:

```
void printb( int (*board)[Col] ) { ... }
```

Again, it's a good idea to pass the number of rows as a separate parameter:

```
void printb( int (*board)[Col], size_t rows )
{
  for ( size_t k = 0; k < rows; k++ )
  {
    for ( size_t l = 0; l < Col; l++ )
      printf( "%4d |", board[k][l] );
    putchar( '\n' );
  }
  putchar( '\n' ); // adding a newline here instead of
}                  // in main
```

---

Style notes:

You went to the trouble of defining the `Row` and `Col` macros, use them.

I've found that life's easier if you define the called functions before the calling functions (if they're both in the same source file, anyway); IOW, put the definitions of `printb` and `revrsboard` *before* `main`:

```
void printb( int (*board)[Col], size_t rows )
{
  ...
}

void revrsboard( int (*board1)[Col], size_t rows, int (*board2)[Row], size_t cols )
{
  ...
}

int main( void )
{
  ...
  printb( board1, Row );
  revrsboard( board1, Row, board2, Col );
  ...
}
```

A function definition also serves as a declaration.  This saves you from having to write a separate declaration, reducing your maintenance burden a bit.  Granted, it means your code reads "backwards".

As written, your `printb` function can't deal with anything that isn't an Nx3 array; you couldn't use it to display `board2`, for example.  You can get around this by using what's called a *variable-length* array, whose size isn't determined until runtime:

```
/**
 * The board parameter can point to arrays with arbitrary
 * numbers of columns; the column size is taken from the
 * cols parameter.  
 *
 * For this to work, the cols parameter *must* be declared
 * before board.  
 */
void printb( size_t rows, size_t cols, int (*board)[cols] )
{
  for ( size_t i = 0; i < rows; i++ )
  {
    for ( size_t j = 0; j < cols; j++ )
      printf( "%4d |", board[i][j] );
    putchar( '\n' );
  }
  putchar( '\n' );
}
```

and then you could use it for *both* `board1` and `board2`:

```
printb( Row, Col, board1 );
printb( Col, Row, board2 );
```

VLAs were introduced with C99 and technically are optional in C2011 and later, but AFAIK they're supported in most modern implementations.

Comment: This is a great answer. Correct and didactic. Why MSVC still doesn't implement VLAs...

Answer (score 1):

1. Remove type `int` from front of function invocations for `printb` and `reversboard` (you don't specify the return type when calling a function)
2. Correct name in function declaration from `initb` to `printb`
3. Functions declared to return `int` so add `return 0;` to the end of each function or change return type to `void`.

You end up with something like the following which compiles and runs:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

#define Row 2
#define Column 3

int printb(int board[2][3]);
int revrsboard(int board1[2][3], int board2[3][2]);

int main() {
  int board1[Row][Column] = {
    {
      1,
      2,
      3
    }, // ο αρχικος πινακας
    {
      4,
      5,
      6
    }
  };

  int board2[Column][Row] = {
    0
  };
  //int  printb(board1); //ektyposh pinaka
  printb(board1); //ektyposh pinaka
  printf("\n");
  //int  revrsboard(board1,board2);  //anastyrofh kai ektyposh
  revrsboard(board1, board2); //anastyrofh kai ektyposh

  return 0;
}

//print 1
int printb(int board[2][3]) {
  int k, l;

  for (k = 0; k < 2; k++) {
    for (l = 0; l < 3; l++) {
      printf("%4d |", board[k][l]);
    }
    printf("\n");
  }
  return 0;
}

// reversing print
int revrsboard(int board1[Row][Column], int board2[Column][Row]) {
  int i = 0, j = 0, k, l;
  for (i = 0; i < Row; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < Column; j++) {
      board2[j][i] = board1[i][j];
    }
  }

  for (k = 0; k < 3; k++) {
    for (l = 0; l < 2; l++) {
      printf("%4d |", board2[k][l]);
    }
    printf("\n");
  }
  return 0;
}
```